# Relative div height based on image

Tags: css

I have two columns with the left being some text with a background color and the right being an image.

Full Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kvFG4/

Here's the basic structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <table style="height:auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="width:35.7143%">
                    <div data-cycle-fx="fade" data-cycle-timeout="5000" data-cycle-speed="2000" data-cycle-slides="li" class="squareMarketingText cycle-slideshow squareMarginTop" id="dnn_squareMarketingTextPane" style="position: relative; height: 548px;">
                        <li style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: block; visibility: hidden;" class="cycle-slide cycle-sentinel">
                            <div class="squareOrange" style="visibility: hidden;">
                                <span class="center marketingText" style="visibility: hidden;">
        CREATING WHAT YOUR BUSINESS NEEDS, TO GO WHERE YOUR BUSINESS NEEDS TO GO
        </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <li style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 97; opacity: 0; display: block; visibility: hidden;" class="cycle-slide">
                            <div class="squareOrange">
                                <span class="center marketingText">
        CREATING WHAT YOUR BUSINESS NEEDS, TO GO WHERE YOUR BUSINESS NEEDS TO GO
        </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width:64.2857%">
                    <img class="plc-logo" src="http://newsite.plcellc.com/Portals/_default/Skins/PLC//images/AllSquares.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

I'd like the text in the left column to be flexible with the right column but the only way I was able to get it to work was with this javascript:

```
setTimeout(function () {
            $(".squareMarketingText").css({ 'height': ($(".plc-logo").height() + 'px') });
        }, 500);
```

Is there away to have the left column be sized right with just .css?

Comment: there´s no class `.plc-logo` inside your html. Basically, if you use div´s inside a td, then you just need to set the `height` to `auto`.

Comment: @alpham8 It's on the <img>. Check out the fiddle, if you remove the javascript the left column gets all wonky

Comment: ok, so, the default behaviour of a table is, that it automatically fits to its content size. So, I think the easiest way to fix it, is to set the height and width attribute to the img tag. Please remember also, that an alt attribute in an img tag is needed, which could also cause problems, if it´s not set.

Comment: @alpham8 I need the image's width to be 100% of it's td. Height will vary based on how much the image is scaled by the browser. So I can't give the image a fixed height in px. It has a height of 100% in the css though.

Comment: 100% css height rule means, that your image get stretched through the height of the complete td. So, to get the excepted behaviour, you just need to change your height property to auto.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - relative positioned parent div not stretching to absolute child div height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184919/css-relative-positioned-parent-div-not-stretching-to-absolute-child-div-height)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<li>` inside a `<div>` tag.... li tags should always be within `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags.

Rest of your code is fine.

**[Check the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kvFG4/2/)**

I turned div in to UL & removed the inline css height.

Comment: I need the height to remain consistent, so the marketing text box can't be taller than the image. Would you know how to achieve that with the ul ?

Comment: dont get confused with UL & div's it more about the css then the tags. The css which worked on div will work the same way on UL.

Comment: And sorry i just noticed that it dosent respond to the change in size

Comment: btw is it important to keep the markup inside td like this? ~ i know other solution but that will require a slightly different markup

Comment: I'd like to leave the div with .squareMarketingText intact, but everything else we should be able to move around

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/npdkC/2/ ~ check this out -- it's a different markup but you can see it is working... in your case i noticed you are using li with position absolute ... parent div can not know the height of child elements if they are position absolute. due to which it wont be able to expand the ul according to the li. to cover height 100%

Comment: **[See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184919/css-relative-positioned-parent-div-not-stretching-to-absolute-child-div-height)** If position: absolute important to keep on li then you should stick with the javascript.

Comment: Ya, I saw that one. I'm not sure if it's the same problem as mine. I have a container element (the TD) I'd like the height to stretch to.