# position relative content calculate height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a position relative container and it's a lot of absolute position div. I want to calculate absolute div's height for the my relative container.
How can i do this with css or jquery? I can't see container's red background...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:300px;background-color:red;">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100px;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>  
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:100px;left:100px;">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get what you want! please clearify

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - relative positioned parent div not stretching to absolute child div height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184919/css-relative-positioned-parent-div-not-stretching-to-absolute-child-div-height)

Comment: @amin jafari, #container doesn't resize by it's child div. becauase child divs are absolute. i want to grow up the container height by it's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the divs are all positioned horizontally (next to each other) and width no left or right margin (which by looking at your code I suppose the conditions are matched) then you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/U6RXB/1/

```
var width=0;
$('#container').children('div').each(function(){
    width=width+$(this).width();
});
$('#container').width(width);
```

if any of the conditions I mentioned are not matched with your code then notice me and I'll fix it again.