# How can I get a relative div to expand to fit its absolute contents?

Tags: html, css, wrapper, absolute

I'd prefer to do this using only CSS.

I have a relative element which contains an absolute element. I want the relative element to be sized based on how big the absolute element is, so in other words it should wrap neatly around it. To illustrate, in this fiddle, "footer" is positioned underneath "header-wrapper", but it overlaps its contents because "header-wrapper" is ignoring its absolute contents: http://jsfiddle.net/cxmjdL78/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="header-1">HEADER HEADER HEADER</div>
        <div class="header-2">HEADER HEADER<br>HEADER HEADER</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">this text should go below the header</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.header-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.header-1 {
    position:absolute;
    background:#232323;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    opacity:0.4;
}
.header-2 {
    position:absolute;
    background:#323232;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    opacity:0.4;
}
.footer {
    position:relative;
    background:#26d452;
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

Comment: Did you try  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184919/css-relative-positioned-parent-div-not-stretching-to-absolute-child-div-height)?

Comment: @Rulisp Sorry I should have been clear, I'm wondering if there's a CSS solution.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use position:absolute on an element, you "take it out of the flow". You can't get a size based on a absolutely positioned element as far as I know. You have to set the height on your header-wrapper, or use javascript to achieve the effect.

Why do you have to use position absolute?

Comment: It would take too long to explain, but this is all I needed to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a CSS only solution, the only thing I can think of is to add a height to your header-wrapper.   If the content in your div is static, this will solve your problem, but if it's dynamic, you're going to be forced into some kind of JavaScript solution.