# Absolutely position div inside container while retaining the container's position in document flow

Tags: css, absolute

I know there's got to be a simple solution to this, but I'm drawing a blank right now.

Here's what I have:

[image: Before]

I want the yellow text block to be absolutely positioned inside its parent container, 10 pixels from the right edge. But when I add "position:absolute" and "right:10px" to .text-block, this is what happens:

[image: After]

I know I can just add a fixed height to the parent container for a quick fix, but this will be on a responsive site, so the parent containers need to have a fluid height and width. Here's my code. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: helvetica;
    color: #333;
   }
   
   #wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
   }
   
   .block {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   
   .text-block {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="block">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis.</p>
   </div> <!-- block -->
   
   <div class="block">
    <div class="text-block">
     <h2>Heading</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis.</p>
    </div> <!-- text-block -->
   </div> <!-- block -->
   
   <div class="block">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis.</p>
   </div> <!-- block -->
  </div> <!-- wrapper -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are misusing absolute position here - it is designed to "cut" the contents out of the page flow and put it somewhere else. Try using float:right or relative positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning does take it out of the flow, so what it's doing is expected. Here's one solution using relative positioning instead, plus a transform to achieve what you want with no markup changes. There are many ways with different `text-align`, `float`, `flex` solutions to handle this.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: helvetica;
    color: #333;
   }
   
   #wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
   }
   
   .block {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   
   .text-block {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
                transform:translate(-100%, 0%);
                -webkit-transform:translate(-100%, 0%);
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="block">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis.</p>
   </div> <!-- block -->
   
   <div class="block">
    <div class="text-block">
     <h2>Heading</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis.</p>
    </div> <!-- text-block -->
   </div> <!-- block -->
   
   <div class="block">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis.</p>
   </div> <!-- block -->
  </div> <!-- wrapper -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I meant the right edge of the yellow box should be 10px from the right edge of the parent container. I'm not familiar with the transform style; is that supported by most browsers? Is this really the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Yours makes the left edge of the yellow box 10px from the right edge of the parent container, making most of the yellow box overflow. It looks like changing left:100% to left:60% will do it.

Comment: So anyway, this seems to work fine in Safari; I'll do some more testing. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Maybe whatever browser you use doesn't support the browser prefix that I can transform. With a definined 40% width, `left:60%` should also work. This solution should work in any modern browser (ie-8 would not work), but you may need some browser prefixing.

Comment: Ah! I just needed to add -webkit- to your original rule to make it work in Safari. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned elements do not affect the parent container height.

You need to use Javascript to change the height as a workaround to this behavior (or, alternatively, use relative positioning).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var objHeight = 0;
    $.each($('.block').children(), function(){
        objHeight += $(this).height();
    });
    $('.block').height(objHeight);
});​
```

This answer is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185521/722617