# CSS : Place a div after a div with a div child of absolute position

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have a problem, i would like to place a div after a div with a div child of absolute position.

What i will like to do is main div to fit with main-inner-one height and normal div to take place after main div

Here is my code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ys1ppfkw/)

```
#main {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#f00;
  padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
  position:relative;
}
#main-inner-one {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#f9c;
  position:absolute;
}
#normal {
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#000;
}

<div id="main">
  <div id="main-inner-one"></div>
</div>
<div id="normal"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Could you [edit] your question with a brief explaination of the intended result and why this does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184919/css-relative-positioned-parent-div-not-stretching-to-absolute-child-div-height

Comment: I would like to know if its possible to do it only with css

Answer (score 0):

To make the `#main-inner-one` stretch across the `#main` you need to remove `absolute` positioning.

[Preview](http://puu.sh/mubM2/98109b77d1.png) - This is how it should've worked.

Answer: Change this

```
#main-inner-one {
    position: relative;
    padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

#main {
    padding:20px 0px 20px 0px; /* remove this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correct you want to adjust the width and height based on the child's width and height. for me this worked by setting the parent div display to table-cell and width, height to auto. the child set display to block and the width, height to vw / vh or anything else except % values.

```
#main {
  display:table-cell;
  position:relative;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  background-color:#f00;
  padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
#main-inner-one {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  height:80vh;
  background-color:#f9c;
}
#normal {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#000;
}
```